# Why my component is not redirecting to the Movies Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

I am using React-Router v6.4 and Vite for React project setup.
Here I am trying to redirect the routes and load the respective components, but it is not redirecting to the movies component.

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Movies from "./components/Movies";

const appRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "movies",
        element: <Movies />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={appRouter} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

main.js

```
// Libraries
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I'm also getting an error:

> Error handled by React Router default ErrorBoundary: Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app.

How do I resolve this as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `App` component is recursively rendering itself, i.e. `App` renders the `BrowserRouter` which renders `App` on route path `"/"` which renders a `BrowserRouter` which renders `App`, ...repeat ad nauseam.

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Movies from "./components/Movies";

const appRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />, // <-- renders another router
    children: [
      { path: "movies", element: <Movies /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={appRouter} /> // <-- renders another App
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This *should have* thrown an invariant error. Something similar to the following:

[image]

`App` should not render itself again within its own sub-ReactTree. You can remove it from the routes and render some other content on `"/"`, like a home page or a redirect to your `"/movies"` path.

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import Movies from "./components/Movies";

const appRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/movies" replace /> },
  { path: "movies", element: <Movies /> }
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={appRouter} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit why-my-component-is-not-redirecting-to-the-movies-page]

[image]